# Level translator as digital buffer

Tags: buffer, level-translation, spectroscopy

In the datasheet of the C12880MA (Mini-spectrometer) they recommend using a digital buffer on pins to and from the module (CLK, ST, EOS, TRG):

[image]

I'm not sure why.

In my case, I need level translation anyway.

Would a bidirectional level translator like the `LSF0204` act as the "Digital buffer"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LSF0204 ([datasheet)](https://www.ti.com/product/LSF0204) can act as a level shifter but it is not a buffer and does not increase the driving capability of the signal. It requires pull-ups on the output side.

[image]

Since you do not need bidirectional capability I would recommend a different type of device.

An TXU0101 ([datasheet)](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txu0101.pdf?ts=1650458893787&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTXU0101) can actively translate and buffer between voltages in the range 1.1V to 5V. There are other family members with multiple devices in the same package. There are two supply voltage pins to set the input and output logic voltage levels.

[image]